# Microsoft Sync Framework Or Replication

Tags: sql-server, replication, microsoft-sync-framework

What is deference between Microsoft Sync Framework  and Replication? which one is better?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1. Sync Framework is a programming framework. You still have to program it yourself. Replication is an end to end feature.
2. Replication solves changes in schemas too (I believe Sync Framework deals with synchronizing data, not schemas)
3. Replication has many more enterprise features already resolved.
4. Sync Framework can be used for not only databases, but anything with a sync provider (replication is only for databases).

I'm sure there are more differences.. but these should give you a start.

Comment: is there any upadate on sync framework now for .net framework 4.5 ,